# asp.net update panel and validators not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, validation

I have created UserControl that contains a textbox and a restricted length validator for that textbox.

I'm adding user controls dynamically via UpdatePanel to my Parent WebForm. And the problem is that Validator just won't work. It just won't trigger.

I work on .net 3.5.

Does anyone have any clue what is happening and how can I make this validator work.

Comment: Actually I've checked right now... The problem is in fact that I'm using my custom validator. With asp validators, everything is ok...

Answer (score 0):

I have face similar problem and my validator in the detailsview-->updatepanel-->Validator

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888031/validator-automatically-on-after-asyncpostback-detailsview) thread for details

On the Client Click I have enable validator using javascript function

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=rfv.ClientID%>'), true);
```

Comment: what is rfv in this cae?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced such an issue. I was using .Net 3.0 and VS2005. I referred to [this problem discussion and the solution](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10060098/validation-is-not-working.aspx) and could solve my issue. You too can refer the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it you can't add controls dynamically as this changes the page structure and .net gets confused.  Instead you have to have all controls loaded "onLoad" and then simply change their visible flag to show or hide them as needed.

This way .net can keep track of them all and is happy.